# InfoWindow: Setting lang attribute inside div tag not working

Tags: google-maps, internationalization, google-maps-markers, html

I am trying to set language attribute to some value other than
"en" [say "ko"] inside a div tag. The content string that I create in
this way is being used to set the InfoWindow's setContent(). Unfortunately, I continue to see the text in English rather than the language value I have defined.
Here are the relevant pieces of code:

```
content_string = '<div style="width: 210px; padding-right: 10px" lang="ko" xml:lang="ko">' + biz_name_html + '<br>' + biz_addr + '<br>' + biz_url_html + '<br>' + biz_phone + '<br>' + biz_description + '</div>';

           marker = new google.maps.Marker({
               position: latlng,
               map: map,
               title: biz_name,
               html: content_string,
               icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage(marker_icon_url)
           });
           google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
               info_window.setContent(this.html);
               info_window.open(map, this);
           });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining the lang attribute will not convert text to a specified language. From the [htmlhelp.com](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/attrs.html)

> The LANG attribute specifies the language of an element's attribute
>   values and its content, including all contained elements that do not
>   specify their own LANG attribute. While the LANG attribute is not
>   widely supported, its use may help search engines index a document by
>   its language while allowing speech synthesizers to use
>   language-dependent pronunciation rules. As well, visual browsers can
>   use the language's proper quotation marks when rendering the Q
>   element.

Actually putting Korean into your div tag (or using the character codes) will display correctly, such as :

```
content_string = '<div style="width: 210px; padding-right: 10px" lang="ko" xml:lang="ko">&#44396;&#44208; &#21475;&#35363;</div>';
```